# VirtualBox error on ubuntu 19.04: Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, 19.04

> **Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)**
>   The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly. Please try setting it up again by executing
>   `'/sbin/vboxconfig'`
>   as root.
>   If your system has EFI Secure Boot enabled you may also need to sign the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.
>   where: suplibOsInit what: 3
>   VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.

[image: screenshot]