# Virtualbox on Ubuntu 19.04 running kernel 5.2.5 : Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, 19.04

I've bought a new laptop on which I have to run kernel 5.1+ because my WiFi-chip (Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX200) wouldn't be supported otherwise. Now, I'm running into problems with VirtualBox.

**The Problem**

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not
set up correctly. Please try setting it up again by executing

'/sbin/vboxconfig'

as root.

If your system has EFI Secure Boot enabled you may also need
to sign the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp,
vboxpci) before you can load them. Please see your Linux 
system's documentation for more information.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908)
The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.
```

**What I tried**

1. `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig`

```
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
The distribution packages containing the headers are probably:
    linux-headers-generic linux-headers-5.2.5-050205-generic
```

I have `linux-headers-generic` installed, and i can not install `linux-headers-5.2.5-050205-generic` because it doesn't exist. `linux-headers-5.2.5-050205` exists and I have installed it, but it doesn't make a difference.

2. `If your system is using EFI Secure Boot...` I have Secure Boot disabled.
3. `sudo modprobe vboxdrv`

`modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found in directory /lib/modules/5.2.5-050205-generic`
The directory exists, but the module is indeed not there.
I tried running `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r) virtualbox-dkms dkms` and reboot but that did not fix the problem

4. `sudo apt remove virtualbox*` and `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-'uname -r' dkms virtualbox-dkms`

This again gives me the error `Package linux-headers-5.2.5-050205-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.`, as with point 1.

5. `sudo apt-get install dkms` and `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`

`sudo: /etc/init.d/vboxdrv: command not found`

6. Both VirtualBox 6 and VirtualBox 5.2 have this problem.

**Possible duplicates**

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1152778/virtualbox-error-on-ubuntu-19-04-kernel-driver-not-installed-rc-1908) possible duplicate leads me to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/920689/how-to-fix-modprobe-vboxdrv-error-in-virtualbox) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41118/virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed) post. I've tried all the solutions there but none work. My largest problem seems to be that `linux-headers-5.2.5-050205-generic` is missing.

Edit : [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41118/virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed) post was marked as possible duplicate, which it is not, as I have explained above.

Comment: How did you install the 5.2 kernel? Why didn't you install headers?

Comment: So why the headers are missing? Install them, and they won't be missing.

Comment: @pilot6 The "generic" version of the headers don't seem to exist. I've installed the kernel according to this article : https://www.osradar.com/install-linux-kernel-5-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.2.5/   It does seem to exist.

Comment: You also could simply install UKUU, that would do everything for you/

Comment: @pilot6 Well I be damned, thanks for that link! I will try to install the generic headers (or the entire kernel) via UKUU, or else via that link.

Comment: @Pilot6 I installed the generic headers manually (I couldn't install ukuu via the ppa, it's not in there) and it works! Thanks a bunch, I'll write and accept the solution. Or is it better to remove this questions, since the solution was obvious in hindsight?

Comment: Both ways are good. Maybe write an answer in case someone else shoots in their foot.

Comment: @Pilot6 You should convert that to an answer and get some rep out of your detective skills...  (voted to leave open, awaiting a ping to come back and upvote)  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby I have lots of rep. And I am confused to post this type of answers. ;-)

Comment: Upvoted OP's both Q and A instead!  **:-)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my own answer, thanks to Pilot6. I followed [this](https://www.osradar.com/install-linux-kernel-5-on-ubuntu-18-04/) guide to install kernel version 5.2.5. Using this guide, I did not install the `generic` version of the headers, which are needed by VirtualBox (see point 1), but the "normal" headers. Manually installing the `generic` headers from [here](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.2.5/) fixed my issue.